# How to Total a while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

Purpose is to put diff ages in, if -1 is entered then the program stops, my totaling statement is wrong.  Will Someone please help me fix it.

```
Totalage = 0

age = 0

print "Enter you Family member's ages!"

age = raw_input ("Enter an age ")

while age != -1:
    age = input("Enter an age ")
    Totalage = Totalage + age

print Totalage
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems with your code

1. You are skipping your first input, and you are not adding it to your total
2. You are adding the last terminator input `-1` to your Total.

Just Change the order of the statements in your while loop

```
age = int(raw_input ("Enter an age "))
while age != -1:    
    Totalage = Totalage + age
    age = int(input("Enter an age "))
```

Also note, `raw_input`, in general returns a string, which needs to be converted to int before you may want to calculate on it.

---

Itertools Provide some wonderful tools, and for fun, I tried coding the above while loop with `itertools.takewhile`

```
>>> from itertools import count, takewhile
>>> sum(takewhile(lambda x: x != -1,
          (int(raw_input("Enter an age ")) for e in count())))
Enter an age 20
Enter an age 30
Enter an age 40
Enter an age 50
Enter an age -1
140
```

Comment: Ha, +1 for the `itertools` solution :)

Comment: @ChristianBraverman: If you are using `raw_input`, then first you need to convert it to integer. Check my Code. Also I am assuming the rest of your codeline remains the same, i.e. initialization of `Totalage`

Comment: I never knew about the `count` function in itertools - perfect for challenges where you want to do everything in a single statement (and probably also useful for more.. umn, useful things ;) )

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `while` condition is working properly, but you don't trigger it until your next run through. Therefore if your input is -1, this:

```
age = input("Enter an age ")
Totalage = Totalage + age
```

Will decrement the age by -1 and on the next loop through it will exit the loop. In order to adjust, you could do something like this. Note that one adjustment is changing `input` to `raw_input` (usually a better practice in Python 2.x, and Python 3.x changes the behavior of `input` to match it):

```
Totalage = 0  
print "Enter you Family member's ages!"
while True:
    age = int(raw_input("Enter an age "))
    if age == -1:
      break
    Totalage += age

print Totalage
```

`while True` puts you into a continuous loop, and you break out of it whenever the value `-1` is entered. Also, the `int` here is what you need to do to convert the number to an integer. This will fail if somebody enters an incorrect value (like 'ten', for instance), so if that is a concern you would have to add some additional error handling.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're adding `-1` to `Totalage` before the loop condition is checked.  You could rewrite the loop something like this instead:

```
print "Enter you Family member's ages!"
Totalage = 0
while True:
    age = input("Enter an age ")
    if age == -1:
        break
    Totalage +=  age
print Totalage
```